# Debugging tools/methods for phonegap blackberry app

Tags: debugging, cordova, blackberry

Are there any tools/methods for debugging phonegap Blackberry(5,6,7) app . Presently am using Alert for debugging which is very tedious .

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using PhoneGap, its always better to view/debug you app on a webkit browser like Chrome/Safari. Also try Ripple emulator from BlackBerry which is the best web emulator for mobile devices: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing a web app, and as far as I know there's no "official" IDE for BlackBerry Webworks, this question is not BB or Phonegap specific. You are just asking how to debug JavaScript. There are a lot of questions in SO about this, just [run a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20debug%20javascript). I'll give you my two cents:

As the JavaScript code runs in a browser, you need to debug in the browser. Most browsers have built-in debugger or extensions. For Firefox I'd reccomend Firebug extension, in Chrome the built-in debugger is pretty good. I can't tell about IE but I think there's something similar.

If you need to debug on device, then use `console` instead of alert.

Finally, have a look at WebStorm. Probably the best IDE for JavaScript right now, but you need to purchase a license. It allows you to attach to the browser debugger and debug in the IDE.